# QGIS 1.6.0 problem during printing & export to PDF

Tags: qgis

When trying to print or export my map to pdf something happens to my document.  When trying to print, the outcome always results in the printer producing a solid grey rectangle, and when I try to export to pdf the file becomes damaged and will not open.  I'm trying to print a 36x24 in map if the size makes any difference.  Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Why don't you try the latest stable qgis release? 1.7

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and installed the 1.7.0 version of QGIS which solved the conversion to PDF issue. Plus it is better than 1.6 in a lot of other issues :)